# Linq SqlMethods NOT Like

Tags: c#, linq

I want all the fields witch dont start with 3 numbers. With the following code I get all the lines that start with a number, I want to have the inverted result.

```
var LEResult = (from t1 in dtClone.AsEnumerable() //TWT
                select t1).Where(q => SqlMethods.Like(q["BillingPeriod"].ToString(), "%[0-9][0-9][0-9]"));
```

How can I do this with Linq?

Comment: `that start with a number` I think it's `that end with a number`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
var LEResult = (from t1 in dtClone.AsEnumerable() //TWT
                select t1).Where(q => !SqlMethods.Like(q["BillingPeriod"].ToString(), "%[0-9][0-9][0-9]"));
```

`SqlMethods.Like` returns `bool` so you only need to add `!` to negate

Comment: Oh crap that was easy, Thanks!